# How to customise a Wordpress theme's expiration date

Tags: php, css, wordpress, subscription, membership

I have bought a listing theme from AIT-club featured with a built membership subscription plan; the theme provides expiration dates per days only. I then look for a registration plugins which provide membership plans per days, weeks, months and years different from those of the theme. Both theme and plugins create subscription plans based on Users roles; users roles are created by the theme, but they can be seen by the plugins too when creating a subscription plan. The plugins does not overwrite the subscription plans created by the theme. That is what I want.

After that I got an idea of just customising the theme's expiration dates and use the plugins for registration/login and receiving payments.

However, I am still not sure if the above solution is going to work well together, in particular when users need to renew their subscription as there is no link between them if users pay via the plugins' payment options.

The second solution is I may need to integrate both the theme's expiration dates and payment options (paypal, paypal recurring and stripe, etc.) with those of plugins?

Could you please give me an idea of which one should work?

Comment: You should probably re-work your question. As someone who is trying to understand what you want, it's difficult to say what would/wouldn't work without looking at actual code. My advice is to try one of your proposed solutions, and then ask questions surrounding why it does / doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I cannot do that myself as I am not a big developer; I did talk to a freelancer about the first solution; there is no doubt he could do that very easily if he does that before. All customisations are placed in the child theme. It cost a lot to try that and I dont think it would work. I can do that only with some guidance not writing codes from scratch. Any advice will be very appreciated